# Why Ubuntu VM on Parallels has a blurry look on Macbook Pro Retina?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, virtual-machine, macbook, parallels

I've installed Ubuntu in a Macbook Pro Retina. It looks terrible, though, even after adjusting the resolution to 2880x1800:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Why this is happening? I have already enabled Retina resolution on video configs of parallels.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68022/how-to-fix-font-rendering-no-anti-aliasing-in-unity-global-menu-and-search install `gnome-tweak-tool` and try different anti aliasing modes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my 2015 MacBook Pro 15" with a Retina Screen, I had to adjust the resolution to the highest (native) setting and then set the scale to 200%:

[image]